# Why using a counter to change an attribute isn't working?

Tags: jquery, counter, attr

At the moment I have all divs with index=1:

```
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
```

I want them to be like:

```
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
<div class="test" index="2"></div>
<div class="test" index="3"></div>
<div class="test" index="4"></div>
```

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
var count = 0;
$('.test').each(function(i) {
    $('.test').attr("index", count);
    count++;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`$('.test').attr` sets the attribute of *all* `.test`s. You need to select the current element being iterated over - either use `this`, or the second parameter of `each`. You also need to start the counter at 1, not 0.

```js
var count = 1;
$('.test').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr("index", count);
  count++;
});
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
```

You can also omit the `count` variable entirely and use the iteration index.

```js
$('.test').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr("index", i + 1);
});
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
<div class="test" index="1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just forgot to select it by $(this).. :)
But I really wanted those index to start with 0. And that's not possible with this code :/